# Select from current point to end

Tags: .net, select, ms-word, office-interop

How can I select from my current selection in a document (nothing is selected, it's just a chosen point) to the end of the document?

Answer (score 1):

The Selection class provides the [Expand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822873(v=office.15).aspx) method which expands the specified range or selection and returns the number of characters added to the range or selection.

Also you may find the [GoTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821348(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Selection class which moves the insertion point to the character position immediately preceding the specified item, and returns a Range object.

The [Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821608(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Document class returns a Range object by using the specified starting and ending character positions.

Don't forget that you can use a Macro recorder which is available in Word. So, you can do the required steps manually in Word and then get a VBA code generated for you. See [Record or run a macro](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Record-or-run-a-macro-cd56fb86-d8b2-475c-ba39-9728389feeeb) for more information.